# How to refer certificate element from KeyInfo in Apache Santuario

Tags: java, xml-signature

I want to create a xml signature with Apache Santuario and KeyInfo should refer the certificate element(BinarySecurityToken) like below

<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-FBB16D2886CB8FE58213384666945692">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-FBB16D2886CB8FE58213384666945693">
<wsse:Reference URI="#X509-FBB16D2886CB8FE58213384666945491"
ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-
profile1.0#X509v3" />
(</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>

But I can't find any support in KeyInfo of Santuario other than adding the certificate and
public key . It will add the certificate as embedded and not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using WSS4J directly .  With Santuario this is not possible as I noticed.